# rails 5 api microservice api authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, microservices

I am looking into building micro services each service made out of a Rails 5 API. The biggest wall I have hit is how to handle building the authentication for users. It looks like OAuth2.0 provides the best structure to follow but I still seem to be lost on a few points. I have figured out 2 different follows that could work.

Flow 1 - 
 [http://imgur.com/a/IjRnW](https://imgur.com/a/IjRnW) ( sorry cant post images)

Flow 2-
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkQ7P.jpg

Flow 1 seems the easier way to get user_id to the APIs.
Flow 2 seems to follow closer to most OAuth implementations but the issue is that you have to constantly check the token with the auth server.

Any help, examples, or tutorials of a clear implementation would be very helpful. Thanks :)